# Convert float to YYYYMM Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The date column that I have in the dataframe is of `float` type.

I was able to convert it in to YYYY-MM-DD format using the below:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%Y%m%d')
```

How can I convert it to YYYY-MM? tried the below and it didn't help.

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%Y%m')
```

Comment: Could you add sample data and expected output as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for string:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%Y%m%d').dt.strftime('%Y%m')
```

Or for month periods:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%Y%m%d').dt.to_period('m')
```